# Where did d'Alembert published the ratio test?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, calculus, publishing, real-analysis

The Wikipedia article [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) states that it was first published by [Jean le Rond d'Alembert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_le_Rond_d%27Alembert). In which of his works did he state the ratio test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link given in the Wikipedia, I reached [Opuscules](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62424s/f192.image), I think here he published the ratio test.